# Apply str.contains for different in strings on pandas dataframe or groupby object in pandas or dask

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dask

I would like to preform str.contains() elementwise with some format like:

```
df['superstring'].str.contains(df['substring'])
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach 1: Preform the operation for each unique substring

This approach works much better in pandas. In dask the number of tasks is very large.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd


def multi_str_contains(dataframe, sub_col, super_col, new_col):
    results = []
    sub_col_unique = dataframe[sub_col].unique()
    if len(sub_col_unique)==0:
        return None
    
    def in_sec(sub):
        sec = dataframe[dataframe[sub_col]==sub].copy()
        sec[new_col] = sec[super_col].str.contains(sub, regex=False)
        return sec
    
    vals = [v for v in [in_sec(sub) for sub in sub_col_unique] if v is not None]
    
    if len(vals)==0:
        return None
    
    return dd.concat(vals)
```